# Exists any library to run rails "migrations" not related to AC in a capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm looking for a library that allows me to run incremental ruby scripts every capistrano deploy (like active record migrations but without a database).

I can't seem to find anything in google.

Answer (score 0):

How about capistrano itself? :)

You can add tasks to run before or after deploy in your deploy.rb file

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc "Do something before deploy."
  task :my_awesome_predeploy_task do
    # do stuff here...
  end

  desc "Do something after deploy."
  task :my_awesome_postdeploy_task do
    # do stuff here...
  end

end

namespace :deploy do
  before :deploy, "deploy:my_awesome_predeploy_task"
  after :deploy, "deploy:my_awesome_postdeploy_task"
end
```

Comment: but I don't want to run the same task every deploy, the idea is to run diferent, incremental, scripts every time. In my case to make changes to an elasticsearch index. But there could be much many use cases.

Comment: you could mimic what migrations are doing, timestamp your 'migration' scripts and when one has run store the timestamp in the db. The pre/post deploy script should then check the latest timestamp in the db and run all scripts that have a later timestamp.